# Finding Thevenin Equivalent Voltage

Tags: electrical-engineering

[image]

What I did was I found the $I_{short circuit(AB)}$ = 10/5 = 2A by shorting AB.

How am I supposed to find $R_{AB}$ in order to solve for $V_{Thevenin}$? It can't be 5//10 right?

Comment: looks like homework... also this belongs in [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No, it's not 5||10.  Replace sources with their ideal resistances.  Voltage sources are 0Ω and Current sources are ∞.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an open circuit,Thevenin Equivalent Voltage is the Open circuit voltage.I use Node Voltage method to find the Thevenin Equivalent Voltage.
Voc = Va - 0
[(Vs - Va)/R1] + Is = (Va/R2)
Va = [Vs+(R1*Is)] / [1+(R1/R2)]
Va = [10+(5*1)] / [1+(5/10)]
Va = (10+5)/[(10+5)/10]
Va = (15/15)(10/1)
Voc = Va = 10V
Therefore, Thevenin’s Equivalent Voltage is 10V.